# Monitor MySQL connections from PHP (Open/Close)

Tags: php, mysql, connection, monitoring

Is there a tool that anyone knows that clearly shows something like this:

```
Opened Connection
   - Qry 1 executed... xyz time
   - Qry 2 executed... abc time
Connection Closed
```

Connections are from PHP to MySQL.

Does any profiler help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes,  `show processlist`

```
mysql> show processlist;
+----+----------+-----------+--------+---------+------+------------+-------------------------------+
| Id | User     | Host      | db     | Command | Time | State      | Info                          |
+----+----------+-----------+--------+---------+------+------------+-------------------------------+
|  5 | jbolivar | localhost | SOF    | Query   |    0 | NULL       | show processlist              |
|  6 | jbolivar | localhost | sakila | Query   |    2 | User sleep | select *,sleep(20) from actor |
+----+----------+-----------+--------+---------+------+------------+-------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

and if you want to kill the process you can use, `kill query $ID`

```
mysql> kill query 6;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

EDIT:

If you need a tool, take a look to [mtop](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mtop/)

Comment: I am aware of processlist command. But I would like to see if thee is a GUI tool available for this, which is much more intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

You can use external tool like Sql profiler for this kind of task. I already have used Jet Sql Profiler (http://www.jetprofiler.com) but it's a commercial solution. I haven't found anything similar to Sql Server Profiler free for MySql yet.